# AssumingRole is not authorized to perform, even if add the policies strategy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

What I am trying to is using my IAM user udagram-xue-dev to assume the role of eksClusterRole. This is my policies configures:

This policy has been add to my IAM user:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/eksClusterRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

This trust policy has been added to my eskClusterRole:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/udagram-xue-dev",
        "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

but I still get this problem:
[image]

I have read a lot of relevant details about this assuming role problem, but I still can't figure out how to fix it. It seems that they all just need to add these policies, then it'll be OK.

Comment: Is there a permissions boundary IAM policy attached to the user?

Comment: I have checked that. No permissions boundary

Answer (score 2):

According to your configuration, everything seems to be in place. However, there might be a different policy (permission boundary, service control policy, or another IAM policy applied to the user) that overrides the permissions.

You can test your policies and find out if there’s anything interfering with your permissions using the [IAM Policy Simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html).

Comment: I know the reason why I don't have the permission. My resource name is wrong in my command. I lack a ":"  in resource name.

Comment: Cool, glad you found the issue!